# iOS 6 AutoPause doesn't work

Tags: ios, geolocation, location, ios6

I've follow the example of AutoPause from "**Session 303 - Staying on track from Location Services**" WWDC 2012

In the example you can see how AutoPause is enabled and there two methods which are called:

```
-(void) locationManagerDidPauseLocationUpdates:(CLLocationManager *)manager
-(void) locationManagerDidResumeLocationUpdates:(CLLocationManager *)manager
```

I've done the same example but these methods aren't never called. 
Who have tried the same?

Answer (score 6):

I'm experimenting with that right now and here are my observations:

**On iPhone 4**, that is not working at all. Even if you set pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically to YES it keeps pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically as NO(0). No warnings, what kind of API design anti-pattern is this!

**On iPhone 5** pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically is YES (1) by default. And locationManagerDidPauseLocationUpdates is called. I'm having a bad luck having the locationManagerDidResumeLocationUpdates called. I'm also puzzled how this is going to be called if GPS is off? Will it be called once user reaches the next network cell? Even that is not my experience, it is not ever called.

So far, looks to me as one of the least consistent changes in iOS6. I might be going with just pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO for all scenarios and will hope that works ok on all models with iOS6.

[Update - 4-Mar-2013]. I looked through the Apple's presentation for location changes in iOS6 and they suggest to use the region changes monitoring to "un-pause" once you get region changes event. Though this is not suitable for my scenarios as user might go/run/drive for a kilometer or two until such an event happens.

Comment: if you try to assign pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = yes on iOS 5, it will crash.

Comment: The above is certainly true, you have to check via respondsToSelector before using this property.

Comment: It works on my iPhone 4 (iOS6). GPS pauses but never resumes when I start moving again.

Comment: @Lukasz when it was paused, where you in background or foreground? I've been told it can even pause in foreground...in which there you can unpause again and get the resume callback, not sure if the unpausing in foreground happens by itself, or if you need to call `startLocationUpdates` inside `locationManagerDidPauseLocationUpdates`. Based on the documents it seems that it's your responsibility to start again (likely you'll want to restart with a reduced accuracy)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found you have to set the property `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically` to `YES`